# This is a currency converter app . Why cant i divide it?

Tags: flutter, error-handling, division

im trying to divide a number by 23 in flutter

I expected to directly get a number back but instead i got this error

> The operator '/' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
> Try defining the operator '/'.

My code is:

```
  print(textEditingController.text/23);
```

Comment: I suspect the `.text` value is, in fact, _text_.  You can't divide text by a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're parsing it as a text, not a number variable, try to change it to

```
print(double.parse(textEditingController.text)/23);
```

Answer (score 4):

The type of `textEditingController.text` is [String](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/text.html) and a String doesn't have a divide [operation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String-class.html#Operators:%7E:text=Operators).

The solution is to convert the `textEditingController.text` String to a number before doing the divide operation like this:

```dart
 final textAsNumber = num.tryParse(textEditingController.text) ?? 0;
  
 print(textAsNumber/23);
```

The first line of code above means we try parsing the text (and setting `textAsNumber` to a `num` type and if it the text can't be parsed to a `num` (thereby returning `null`), we set `textAsNumber` to`0`.